# Web pages with examples of really stupid HTML

Tags: html

I stumbled upon this site http://www.fujinonbinos.com/, and almost laughed out loud at the ridiculous use of the `<font>` tag. Seriously, do a View Source!

So, I coudn't resist a post here to enquire if anyone else had any other spectacular examples of web pages with daft/stupid/crazy HTML that we could all visit and mock mercilessly!

CW for this one, so fire away :-)

Comment: wow that's awesome. Also: "government binoculars"?

Comment: @Pointy - Yeah! You now know what you are being watched with!

Comment: Unfortunately, GeoCities is closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a joke from a while back. The outline of all the `<font>` tag forms the skyline of Mount Fuji or something. Can't find the link right now but it's definitely intentional, and an easter egg.

Comment: +1, although that kind of spoiled it for me :-) Heres the link: http://www.geeksaresexy.net/2009/09/01/a-hidden-gem-in-html/

Comment: I also saw a picture of Jesus in my toast this morning.

Answer (score 3):

http://yvettesbridalformal.com/

Where everything is made of absolutely positionned tables wrapped in divs

Comment: @marcgg: Holy crap. Besides taking up 1/2GB of ram that bastard blistered my retina and crashed my browser. I did get a chance to look at the nightmare called source though. Holy geebus.

Comment: wow..what kind of person designed that website?!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I remembered this one from a while back:

http://www.milliondollarhomepage.com/

Still, the boy made a million, so maybe we can't mock too much.

Answer (score -2):

http://www.fujinonbinos.com/

that person seems great designer,,,,, lots of font tags,,,,,

and also the title of the site seems "index"

Comment: didn't you read the original post?